# JFrame can't close after ServerSocket (or socket) is created

Tags: java, swing, sockets, serversocket

I'm creating a multiplayer game, but when I create the ServerSocket, I can't close down any JFrames running in that application, here's my server creation code:

```
private void createServer() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cow Invaders - Server");
        JTextArea console = new JTextArea();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        console.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 15));
        console.setLineWrap(true);
        frame.add(console);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(port));
            System.out.println("No problems here");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("An error has occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        console.append("Started server on port " + port + " and with an IP of " + server.getInetAddress());
        try {
            socket = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("An error has occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        console.append("\n" + "Connection from: " + socket.getInetAddress());
        try {
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("An error has occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.writeUTF("You have successfully joined the game.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("An error has occurred" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully send data.");
    }
```

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be doing everything on a single thread, including use of blocking code, and this will block the Swing event thread, preventing it from doing its necessary activities. I'm guessing that with this code your JFrames get frozen. Suggestions:

- Make all Swing calls on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). If your GUI starts on this thread, then you're already set for most of your Swing calls.
- Make all long-running task calls in a background thread. A SwingWorker works well for this, but again as long as you don't make Swing calls directly from the background threads.
- If your application is creating multiple sub-windows, they should be dialog windows, such as JDialogs, and not JFrames.

Check out [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more on this.